# Resaltar filas duplicadas en Excel con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

estoy tratanto de resaltar las filas duplicadas en una hoja de Excel, para ello estoy usando el siguiente codigo:

```
Sub marcardupfilas()
Dim i As Double
'Definimos las fila que queremos analizar y marcar elementos duplicados
fin = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A:A"))
For i = 2 To fin
'Definimos el rango de cada fila, desde la celda 1 hasta el final de la hoja
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 256)).Select
'Indicamos para cada fila y rango seleccionado el mismo proceso mediante un bucle
'donde debe encontrar las celdas que se repitan en cada fila y marcarlas en azul.
With Selection
'borramos formatos condicionales previos
.FormatConditions.Delete
'utilizamos el método FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues para detectar
'valores unicos o duplicados
.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
'seleccionamos y marcamos en azul los valores duplicados
.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
End With
Next
End Sub
```

El mismo solo resalta con color los campos que son iguales en la misma fila, pero necesito modificarlo para que me resalte filas completas que esten duplicadas.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ordénalas, luego comparas la fila actual con la fila anterior y se resalta si son las mismas.

Comment: En este caso no puedes hacerlo con Formato Condicional porque lo que tú quieres es *filas completaS*. Es decir, quieres ver si las 256 celdas de una fila coinciden con las 256 celdas de otra fila. Puedes hacer un bucle y pintarlo tú, o quizás podrías concatenar las 256 celdas en una sola y entonces aplicar formato condicional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes Estimado,

Lo que yo haría como dice en el comentario, concatena todos los valores en una columna 257, tipo =CONCATENAR(A1;B1;C1...etc) hasta tu columna 256, de igual manera podrías hacer una macro que sea directamente:

aux=""

for i=1 to 256
Cells(1, 256)=aux + Cells(1, i)
next i

y claro en lugar del 1 otro for para todas tus filas, para tener todo concatenado en la columna 257, esto en el caso de que se tenga llenado las celdas perfectamente sin espacios ni caracteres especiales como algún punto demás o algo así, caso contrario te aconsejaría eliminar los caracteres especiales con otra macro (tengo una pero en excel la podrías modificar para que sea para VBA).

Esto debido a que comparará exactamente cada carácter en cada posición y si difiere solamente en un carácter pues no se resaltará.

Luego cambiar:

.FormatConditions(257).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
.FormatConditions(257).Interior.Color = vbBlue

Otra alternativa es hacerlo directamente desde el excel, el cual tendrías que concatenar de igual manera en la columna 257, pero el excel te hace automático lo demás, en la pestaña inicio, formato condicional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O de ultimo un hibrido entre ambos, que es lo que haría yo, que el concatenado lo haga en VBA y la comparación lo haga por defecto el Excel.

Saludos espero te sirva en algo mi respuesta.

JLM